# How can I predict the true label for data with incomplete features based on the model learned by data with complete features?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, training-data, feature-engineering, machine-learning-model

for example, the model was learned by training data with complete features (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6)

but, I wonder the model can test data with incomplete features (f1,f2,f3) to attach true label into these test dataset

I am waiting for ML specialist's answer

Thank you so much !!

Comment: Do you mean that feature f4, f5, f6 are missing for some samples in the test data?

Comment: Yes, your thinking is right